# Embedding Sample QuickTime (.mov) video

Tags: quicktime, sample, mov

I need to display sample .mov video on my site, I need one that won't be deleted anytime soon and the host won't block me me for embedding it on my website.

Unfortunately sample QuickTime files on Apple's site are compressed: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425 :(

Have you got any other rock solid sources?

Answer (score 0):

Use this link:
 trac.foswiki.org/export/5630/branches/Release01x00/TinyMCEPlugin/pub/System/TinyMCEPlugin/tinymce/examples/media/sample.mov

uploaded 4 years ago and i think this won't be deleted soon.